# Can we mock a function inside a node module component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, snapshot

I have a checkbox component coming as a node module to my app,

CHECKBOX Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import uuidv4 from 'uuid/dist/v4';

export default ({inputProps}) => {
    let id = uuidv4();
    return (
            <input
                type="checkbox"
                {...inputProps}
                id={id}
            />
    );
};
```

In my App.js, I'm using CheckBox Component

```
import React from 'react';
import Checkbox from '@checkbox'; // path from the node module

export default () => {
    return (
       <Checkbox 
          {...{
            inputProps: {
                checked: false,
                onChange: () => {}
            }
        }}
       />
    )

};
```

Test file:

```
import {mount} from 'enzyme';

describe('test App', () => {
it('should render the component', async () => {
        const component = mount(<App />);
        expect(component).toBeDefined();
        expect(component.html()).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
});
```

These are the sample components I've added
I don't want to mock the entire Checkbox component coz I want to test the checkbox behavior.
**Is there any way that I can mock the `uuid` function in Checkbox component** since it's generating a new UUID every single time I update the snapshot without any actual component changes.
I tried mocking the UUID function

```
jest.mock('uuid/dist/v4', () => {
    return () => 'test id';
});
```

This mocks any of the usages in my app but not the function inside the Checkbox component or any other node module.
*please ignore if any imports missed*

I'm able to run the tests successfully but I want to find out a way to ignore the UUID generation in snapshots files.

Comment: did you find any solution? Facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

You probably shouldn't import from `package/dist/`, try

```
import { v4: uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
```

and to mock, try using this:

```
jest.mock("uuid", () => {
  return {
    v4: () => 'test id'
  }
});
```

See also a playground (it works): https://repl.it/@kiprasmel/jest-playground

Comment: apparently the default usage changed. See the updated answer - should work just fine now.

Comment: As I mentioned in the description, if uuid is set in the App.js file as in your playground, we can mock that. But can I mock the function in node module?
In my case, I'm trying to test App.js which contains Checkbox component imported from node modules which has uuid generation in it. Can I mock the uuid generated in Checkbox component?

Comment: why would you need that? To mock only once? Then you should use jest.mockImplementation and then either .mockClear, .mockReset or .mockRestore depending on your use case. See https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockclear

Comment: Since uuid is getting generated outside of my app, even if I mock `uuid` in my app, it's still generating random id in the snapshot files.

Comment: sorry, I do not understand:/

Comment: @codegig 
did you find any solution? Facing the same issue.